# How can I refer to a function?

Tags: c++, function, reference, sfml

I'm learning C++ and SFML right now, trying to create a chess program in which I can drag and drop the pieces around the board.  I drag the pieces by checking if the left mouse button is down and if the mouse is over a piece.  If these are both true, I change the position of the piece to that of the mouse.

The only problem is when I drag the pieces really quickly, thus having my mouse down but not hovering over the piece.

I want to fix this using something like:

```
sf::Sprite pieceSelected;
sf::Sprite Pawn;
bool selected;
```

...

```
if (LeftButtonDown && isMouseOver(Pawn,Input)) {
        pieceSelected=&Pawn;
        selected = true;
    }

    if (LeftButtonDown && selected)
        pieceSelected.SetPosition(MouseX - (XSizeSprite / 2), MouseY - (YSizeSprite / 2)); 
    else
        selected=false;

    App.Draw(Pawn);
```

I want 'pieceSelected' to be referencing 'Pawn' so that when I'm moving 'pieceSelected' I'm actually moving 'Pawn' at the same time.

**EDIT**

I fixed this by changing

```
sf:Sprite pieceSelected;
```

to

```
sf::Sprite * pieceSelected;
```

and

```
pieceSelected.SetPosition
```

to

```
pieceSelected->SetPosition
```

Comment: You'll probably want a pointer, seeing as how you can change pieces and sometimes not have a piece at all.

Comment: `sf::Sprite Pawn; sf::Sprite & pieceSelected = Pawn;`

Comment: the `else` part of `if (LeftButtonDown && selected)` is not necessary.

Comment: If I use sf::Sprite & pieceSelected = Pawn; I get the error: left of '.SetPosition' must have class/struct/union

Comment: @PearSquirrel: The problem is that Petr Budnik's solution, placed inside your `if`-statement, declares `pieceSelected` for the duration of only that it-statement. Your current code uses it outside the if-statement. The code as we now see it is weird. Why not just `if (LeftButtonDown && isMouseOver(Pawn,Input)) { Pawn.SetPosition(...); }` ?

Comment: @MSalters If I only use that code, my mouse will drop the piece if I move it too fast because the mouse will not be hovering over the piece after a certain point.

Comment: I figured it out (change .setPosition to ->setPosition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, from the comments I spotted the problem. Your drag-and-drop code repeatedly picks up and drops the pawn. That's indeed not the correct solution. Instead, you should only drop the piece on a `LeftMouseUp`.

What you want is a `DragOperation` class. You create it when you detect the begin of a drag operation (mouse down over a pawn). The `DragOperation` class has a `sf::Sprite & pieceSelected`, set of course in its constructor. You should also store both the mouse *and* pawn coordinates where the drag operation started.

While dragging, the responsibility of drawing the selected piece should be moved to the `DragOperation` class. This allows you to smoothly drag the pawn, in pixel increments, instead of drawing it only in the middle of a square.

When the mouse button is released, check the result and then delete your `DragOperation` object.

Comment: Ah, that's smart.  I compensated for the dropping part with the bool 'selected' but this is a way better method.  Thank you!